# loading the signin before the home page with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a POST to website x which requires a login but the problem is that the page load before siginin(check the console.log) how to fix this please

```
var request = require("request");

var headers = {
    authority: "",
    origin: url,
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    cookie: "",
};

var dataString = "";

var options = {
    url: loginUrl,
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString,
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log("login successfully");
    }
}

async function ok() {
    await request(options, callback);
    let result = await request.get(websiteUrl);
    const page = result.data;
    console.log("page loading");
}
ok();
```

**console.log:**

```
page loading
login successfully
```

Answer (score 2):

The `request` package is deprecated. It does not support promises/async/await. Use a package such as [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which supports promises, hence supporting async/await.

```
var axios = require("axios")

...

async function ok() {
    await axios(options, callback);
    let result = await request.get(websiteUrl);
    const page = result.data;
    console.log("page loading");
}
```

You may have to change the format of `options`, as per docs, but it should be similar to above.